# Cannot get file upload/attachment with Sprout Forms working

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, plugin-sproutemail, files

I'm trying to add an file upload/attachment to my Sprout Form submission, but even though all the other fields are saved & the Sprout Email notification is sent - the file field remains empty - no file is uploaded & so no attachment is sent.

- I've checked that my form contains enctype="multipart/form-data"
- I've checked that the file type I'm trying to upload is an allowed file
  type for the Asset folder ie: PDF
- I've checked that the file is a reasonable size - in this case 3KB
- I've checked the craft log, sprout forms log & sprout email log & there are no errors.

Anyone have any ideas ? Below is my form code - what am I missing ?

```
<form id="careerApplication" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sproutForms/entries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="handle" value="careerApplication">      
<fieldset>
    {{ craft.sproutForms.displayField('careerApplication.fullName') }}
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="fields[refNo]">Reference #</label>
    <input type="text" name="fields[refNo]" id="fields-refNo" readonly value="{{ craft.request.getParam('ref') }}" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    {{ craft.sproutForms.displayField('careerApplication.email') }}
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    {{ craft.sproutForms.displayField('careerApplication.telephone') }}
</fieldset> 
<fieldset>         
    <label for="motivation">Motivation</label>
    <textarea name="fields[motivation]" id="fields-motivation" placeholder="Motivation"></textarea>
</fieldset> 
<fieldset>
    <label for="cvUpload">Submit your CV:</label>
    <input type="file" name="fields[cvUpload]" id="fields-cvUpload" />    
</fieldset>                   
{{ craft.sproutInvisibleCaptcha.protect() }}
<input id="submit_application" name="submit_application" type="button" value="Submit Application" class="red-btn" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out what my problem was: I was trying to submit the form via Ajax, that's why the submit button is set to input type="button" 
I changed the submit button to input type="submit" & it worked.
Not 100% sure how to make it work with Ajax but pretty sure it has something to do with the way the data is serialized. I don't really need Ajax submission in this instance, so not bothering with it anymore.